# Winforms Combobox SelectedValue is Null

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a data entry form that had several comboboxes on it.  Each of the combo boxes has its own binding source and it is populating correctly when I launch the form.  However, if I edit the record on the form and try to pass to the database the updated selectedvalue from the combobox I get an error that the value I am passing it NULL.

This issue seems to happen every other time I run the darn thing and I can't figure out why it is not working properly.  Basically I am trying to insert a new record into a table but for some reason it is failing to pull my selected value.  My code to insert the data is below:

```
Data.Manager.AddEmployee
 (
   InactiveEmployeeSelected.GUID,
   Convert.ToByte(RoleComboBox.SelectedValue),
   NotesTextBox.Text.Trim(),
   ScheduleTextBox.Text.Trim(),
   ExtensionTextBox.Text.Trim(),
   CodeTextBox.Text.Trim(),
   Convert.ToBoolean(EBApprovedCheckbox.CheckState),
   Convert.ToByte(ApprovalLevelComboBox.SelectedValue),        //pulling null
   Convert.ToBoolean(AssignComtracksCheckbox.CheckState),
   Security.Manager.CurrentUser.GUID,
   DateTime.Today,
   Convert.ToBoolean(IsActiveCheckbox.CheckState)
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you using a `DropDownStyle` of `DropDown` and typing into the ComboBox?  If so, that will cause `SelectedValue` to be null, I'm assuming because the value entered is no longer one of the items in the `ComboBox`.

If this is the case, set the `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`, assuming the user has to pick an existing value.

Comment: Worked for me (over 5 years later), the default `DropDownStyle` is `DropDown`, rather than `DropDownList`. When set to the latter, the user can't edit the options, and I can get and set using the `SelectedItem` property.

Answer (score 22):

Maybe, you just need to use the [`SelectedItem`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2006/11/07/combobox-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedwhat.aspx), instead!

Answer (score 12):

ComboBox has to have DataSource. Link data though ComboBox1.DataSource

Comment: This should be the answer actually.  If you create an anon type and add items then use DisplayMember and ValueMember, the selectedItem property works but SelectedValue is always null (in my case).  If you create a new list then use the combobox.Datasource property, the SelectedValue is populated correctly.  Strange!