# Winforms comboboxes and parameterized stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, combobox

In my tblSates Table, I have a column named Monat with these three values
[01.2016, 02.2016 and 03.2016] and I want to fetch these values in a combobox.

I am getting the values but just two of them instead of all three.

Here is my code:

```
private void FillCombobox2()
{
    string S = ConfigurationManager

    // TSQL-Statement
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT DISTINCT Monat from tblSales");            
    SqlDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (myReader.Read())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(myReader);
            combobox1.DisplayMember = "Monat";
            combobox1.ValueMember = "Monat";
            combobox1.DataSource = dt;
            combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Will appreciate any help or an alternative solution.

Comment: `cbPeriode1.SelectedValue` is null, show how you fill `combobox` with values

Comment: `private void FillCombobox()
        {          
            string S = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(S);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.CommandText = select distinct Monat from tblSales");
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    cbPeriode1.Items.Add(myReader["Monat"]);
                }
            
`

Comment: Can this [Stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3867983/1565525) be helpful in your case?

Comment: @Fabio. Unfortunately no

Comment: As I sad, your `cbPeriode1.SelectedValue` is null. `SelectedValue` will be always null in your case because combobox was filled by manual adding of items, without using of `ValueMember`. Why you cannot use `SelectedItem` for sqlparameter `cbPeriode1.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed reader.Read and then call which advanced the position (and skipped one of my three records). Alternatively I could have used `if (myReader.HasRows)`.

```
private void FillCombobox2()
{
    string S = ConfigurationManager

    // TSQL-Statement
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT DISTINCT Monat from tblSales");            
    //SqlDataReader myReader;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
     SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ad.Fill(dt)             
            combobox1.DisplayMember = "Monat";
            combobox1.ValueMember = "Monat";
            combobox1.DataSource = dt;
            combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1;

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it an answer or an update of the code in your question? If the former - please add some explanations, if the latter - move the update to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, worth adding some explanation what has changed and why the change fixes the original issue. Can be useful for future generations. Thanks.