# ComboBox SelectedValue is null

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, bindingsource

I'm trying to get the `.SelectedValue` of a `ComboBox`, but it keeps returning `null` instead of the actual value in `.ValueMember`. I tried a couple of different approaches, and came up with this:

```
DataTable datatable = DataAccess.GetDataTable(DateTime.Now); // Get DataTable from DB call
if (datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    List<object> items = new List<object>();
    foreach (DataRow row in datatable.Rows)
    {
        items.Add(new { Text = Convert.ToString(row["PersFullName"]), Value = Convert.ToString(row["PersNbr"]) });
    }

    this.cmbDDLFilter.DisplayMember = "Text";
    this.cmbDDLFilter.ValueMember = "Value";
    this.cmbDDLFilter.DataSource = items;
}
```

This will work when setting the visual part of the `ComboBox`, but when I do this:

```
long nbr = Convert.ToInt64(this.cmbDDLFilter.SelectedValue);
```

The `.SelectedValue` will be `null` even though I set the `.ValueMember` to `"Value"`.

I notice though that the `.SelectedText` is also `null`, but the `.SelectedItem` does indeed have the object I added to the list.

How do I get the anonymous object's `.Value` to actually work with `.SelectedValue`?

I've used this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3063320/combobox-adding-text-and-value-to-an-item-no-binding-source/12936557#12936557) as a reference, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Could you post full form code?

Comment: If you have a nice neat DataTable just use that as the DataSource.  No need to create new anon types and place in a new list of object (which will not have a `Value` property)

Comment: Pls check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867784/winforms-combobox-selectedvalue-is-null

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmbDDLFilter.SelectedIndex = cmbDDLFilter.FindStringExact("Value")
```